# No SRC file in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, src

I'm quite new to Eclipse and PyDev and programming in general. I can't find the SRC file. Currently I'm using the latest Eclipse and PyDev and I cannot see the src file anywhere. I'm trying to make a program following this tutorial (http://www.vogella.com/articles/Python/article.html) and I cannot find the src file and thus cannot continue the tutorial. I would like some help on how to make the file or find it and any problems I may have created. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you create the project, as shown there? Anyway, I wouldn't recommend Eclipse as a first environment for a Python programmer. Python comes with a basic editor, IDLE: you should probably use that.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Thanks for the help. I'll try and use IDLE first.